# Code that have exact function like oct() in Python

Tags: python, function, built-in, octal

I need code that have exact function like `oct()` in Python but without using any other methods and functions.
I wrote this, but I think it's so large and also I don't want use `range` and `len`:

```py
def get_oct(x):
    next_step = [x]
    r_mod = []
    while True:
        x /= 8
        i = int(x)
        next_step.append(i)
        if int(x / 8) == 0:
            break
    for m in range(len(next_step)):
        next_step[m] %= 8
        j = int(next_step[m])
        r_mod.append(j)
    t_mod = r_mod[::-1]
    return "0o" + "".join(str(e) for e in t_mod)

entry = int(input("Enter a number: "))
print(get_oct(entry))
```

Comment: It seems that your code currently works, and you are looking to improve it. Generally these questions are too opinionated for this site, but you might find better luck at [CodeReview.SE](//codereview.stackexchange.com/tour). Remember to read [their requirements](//codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) as they are a bit more strict than this site.

Comment: The function you have does not work *exactly* like `oct()`, if it did I would expect theses assertions to pass: `assert(get_oct(0) == oct(0))` and `assert(get_oct(-10) == oct(-10))`

Answer (score 1):

If you want this to work like the built-in `oct()`, you need to account for zero and negative numbers. A nicer way to deal with this is to use the function [`divmod()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#divmod) the returns the result of integer division and the remainder. Just keep doing that until the value is zero:

```
def get_oct(x):
    if x == 0: return '0o0'
    prefix = '-0o' if  x < 0 else '0o'
    x = abs(x)
    res = ''
    while x:
        x, rem = divmod(x, 8)
        res = str(rem) + res
        
    return (prefix + res)

assert(get_oct(80) == oct(80))
assert(get_oct(1) == oct(1))
assert(get_oct(0) == oct(0))
assert(get_oct(-2) == oct(-2))
assert(get_oct(-201920) == oct(-201920))
assert(get_oct(12345678910) == oct(12345678910))
```

Answer (score 0):

If all that is needed is to print in octal without `oct()` function,string formatting could be the easiest option.

```py
num = int(input("Enter a number: "))
print("{:o}".format(num))
```

Output:

```
Enter a number: 10
12
```

This is also possible with string variable

```
num = int(input("Enter a number: "))
s = "{:o}".format(num)
print(s)
```

Output:

```
Enter a number: 10
12
```